# nontrivial $K$-automorphism of $K(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, rational-functions, fixed-points

How can I find $K$-automorphism $\sigma \in \mathrm{Aut}(K(x))$ different from identity  such that $\sigma (x(x+1))=x(x+1)$?

Comment: you have some idea regarding this problem?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't have any. For a while I was thinking that $x \mapsto \pm x$ or $x \mapsto \pm (x+1)$ but it's not true. Can you give me just some tips?

Comment: Some of your thoughts are correct. What lead you to conclude that it's not true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: The $K$-automorphisms of $K(x)$ are precisely the maps of the form $x\ \mapsto\ ax+b$ with $a\in K^{\times}$ and $b\in K$. Hence you want to find a solution $(a,b)\neq(1,0)$ to the equation
$$(ax+b)(ax+b+1)=x(x+1).$$

Comment: Thanks, however I want to make sure if I'm right in one more thing. You have written that such automorphisms have the form $x \mapsto ax+b$ for proper $a,b$. Is that because $x$ can not be map to constant (otherwise everything would be mapped to this constant) and if $x \mapsto f(x)$ where $\deg f >1$ we wouldn't obtain linear polynomials in the image of automorphism?

Comment: Yes, this is essentially the argument.

Comment: BTW: I may be missing something basic, however: Is there an easy way to see that these are precisely all the automorphisms of $K(x)$? Why can't be the element $x$ be mapped to some non-trivial rational function?

Comment: (I actually think there are more $k$-automorphisms of $k(x)$. Namely, the one induced by the map $x\mapsto x^{-1}$.)

Comment: @PavelC you are correct. For some reason I had $K[x]$ in mind the whole time. There are also the automorphisms of the form $x\ \mapsto\ (ax+b)^{-1}$, with $a\in K^{\times}$ and $b\in K$.